# Do we need both orange and orange3 tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

Recently many [orange](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/orange) posts have had the [orange3](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/orange3) tag also added.  Is there a compelling reason for the existence of both tags?

At time of posting, there are 77 questions tagged with [orange3](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/orange3) and 179 with [orange](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/orange), the former being almost a subset of the latter (one counterexample, I think).

Comment: A status update has been made to the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is interesting you bring this up, I was thinking about this the other day. I think this is a good point.

Perhaps it would make more sense to merge them? I have been adding the Orange3 tag to relevant questions recently thereby increasing it use - however I am not sure any question asked recently refer specifically to any earlier versions of the software. For reference Stack Overflow only has one tag `Orange` and *does not* have a separate tag for `Orange3`.

An analogue of this would be having a `python` tag and a `python2` tag. The latter is not likely to garner much use as older versions become superannuated.

More explicitly - I do not think having a separate tag for versions makes the most sense as likely almost all questions asked at this time will be included in this subset as you mentioned.

**Status Update 11/25/22:**

The [orange3](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/orange3) tag has officially been removed. **Why was this done?** In addition to the many great points outlined above, here are some quick reasons:

- There is no distinction between versions on the larger site Stack Overflow (there is just one tag [orange](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/orange))
- There was less site-wide interest in the [orange3](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/orange3) tag compared to the [orange](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/orange) tag (only 5 watchers compared to the 44 on the more general tag)
- There is enough semantic similarity between both of these tags that there is no real reason to have the distinction (most questions on Orange just simply included both tags)
- Any question about Orange is likely implicitly referring to Orange 3+ as older versions have been superannuated (the [earliest release of Orange](https://github.com/biolab/orange3/releases?page=4) on its GitHub page is for version 3.1 and was released on Nov 10, 2014)
- There were relatively little usage of the [orange3](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/orange3) tag relative to the [orange](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/orange) tag (10 questions asked this year compared to 29 on the main tag)

Comment: Thanks!  I've set a tag synonym `orange3`->`orange`.